# Create screenshot only on test failure

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I have a function that creates a screenshot and I call it here

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.save_screenshot()
    self.driver.quit()
```

There is also a folder being created which is used to store the screenshots.

I don't want this to happen when the test passes.

What do I have to add in order for this not to happen?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Could you share how do you run the tests? Thanks.

Comment: Idk what you mean, like command line or the unit test?

Comment: How do you run them from the command-line, right. Also, what python version are you using?

Comment: v2.7.8 and python test.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to capture screenshot only when failure:

```
def setUp(self):
    # Assume test will fail
    self.test_failed = True

def tearDown(self):
    if self.test_failed:
        self.save_screenshot()

def test_something(self):
    # do some tests
    # Last line of the test:
    self.test_failed = False
```

The rationale behind this approach is when the test reaches the last line, we know that the test passed (e.g. all the self.assert* passed). At this point, we reset the `test_failed` member, which was set to True in the `setUp`. In `tearDown`, we now can tell if a test passed or failed and take screenshot when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If your test failed, the [sys.exc_info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) will have an exception. So you can use it as pass/fail result of your test:

```
if sys.exc_info()[0]:
    # 'Test Failed'
else:
    # 'Test Passed'
```

And if you want to take a screenshot on failure:

```
import unittest
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

class UrlTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def test_correct_url(self):
        self.driver.get('https://google.com')
        self.assertTrue('something.com' in self.driver.current_url)

    def tearDown(self):
        if sys.exc_info()[0]:
            self.driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot.png')
        self.driver.quit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your initialisation method set a `self.NoFailuresSnapped = 0` and check your test environment for the current number of failures being `> self.NoFailuresSnapped` before calling or within your function and of course set it again before returning.